# Exception when registering UnityPerRequestHttpModule with MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I use Unity3 with MVC5, and need per request life time manager. However, when I launch the web app, I got server error saying "Cannot register a module after the application has been initialized." The problem is caused by the DynamicModuleUtility. How to solve this problem?

```
public static void Start()
{
    var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();

    FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.OfType<FilterAttributeFilterProvider>().First());
    FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new UnityFilterAttributeFilterProvider(container));
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    //use per request life time manager
    DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem. My problem was this:

In the GlobalAsax.Application_Start() method I had written.

```
UnityMvcActivator.Start();
```

When I removed it, everything worked. 
When you use the UnityMvcActivator class, the Start method is already called through the annotation:

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(TrackingServer.App_Start.UnityWebActivator), "Start")]
```

So you don't need to call the UnityMvcActivator methods in the Global.asax file again.

Answer (score 1):

For MVC, you want to put this in a class in the App_Start folder. If you add unity for MVC as a nuget package, I think it should create a class called UnityMvcActivator in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I solved this by removing from UnityConfig.cs the following:

```
DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```

and adding this to Unity.Mvc.Activator.cs

```
 // TODO: Uncomment if you want to use PerRequestLifetimeManager
             Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper.DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(UnityPerRequestHttpModule));
```